# Cannot grep jobs list when jobs called in a function

Tags: bash, pipe, function, jobs, subshell

I can `grep` the output of `jobs`, and I can `grep` the output of a `function`. But why can't I grep the output of `jobs` when it's in a function?

```
$ # yes, i can grep jobs
$ jobs
[1]+  Running          vim
[2]+  Stopped          matlab

$ jobs | grep vim
[1]+  Running          vim

$ # yes, of course i can grep a function
$ type mockjobs
mockjobs is a function
mockjobs ()
{
    echo '[1]+ Running         vim banjo'
}
$ mockjobs | grep vim
[1]+ Running         vim banjo

$ # now put those two together and surely I can grep???
$ type realjobs
realjobs is a function
realjobs ()
{
    jobs
}
$ realjobs | grep vim
$ # Nope, WTF?

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

$ # funny though, redirection works just fine:
$ tmpfile=$(mktemp); realjobs > $tmpfile; grep vim $tmpfile; rm $tmpfile
[1]+  Running          vim
```

I'm not seeing a bug in the bash list, but maybe I missed it? There's reference to an [issue in Bash 2.02](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x733.html) when `jobs` is part of a pipeline, but nothing recent and in a function that I can find.

What am I missing here?

Comment: +1; the [source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/jobs.c#n1665)  seems to indicate that jobs would print to stdout

Comment: Uh... I'd open a bug against bash, as this is wacky.

Comment: `echo "$(realjobs)" | grep vi` works too.

Comment: It don't work in `function` too.`function testjobs(){jobs | grep vi}`and`function testrealjobsgrep(){realjobs | grep vi}`.The testjobs can work,but the testrealjobsgrep can't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eric Blake [answered](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2016-04/msg00134.html) on the bash-bugs mailing list:

> `jobs` is an interesting builtin - the set of jobs in a parent shell is
>   DIFFERENT than the set of jobs in a subshell.  Bash normally creates a
>   subshell in order to do a pipeline, and since there are no jobs in that
>   subshell, the hidden execution of jobs has nothing to report.
>
> Bash has code to special-case `jobs |` when it can obviously tell that
>   you are running the jobs builtin as the sole command of the left side of
>   a pipe, to instead report about the jobs of the parent shell, but that
>   special-case code cannot kick in if you hide the execution of jobs,
>   whether by hiding it inside a function as you did, or by other means
>   such as:
>   `eval jobs | grep vim`

Comment: Looks like `zsh` doesn't have the special-case `jobs |` :|